# Two For Loops Using %1 - Delayed Expansion?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, delayedvariableexpansion

My working batch file scans a long list of remote servers, copies anything there to a local server, checks the log file for a keyword, and if the keyword is found sends an email. I noticed it is always sending emails, even with a blank log file.

I discovered both `FOR` loops are using the `%1` variable for their output - as seen in `ECHO %1` and each line of the called `:servermove`. For lack of a better explanation it is not resetting `%1` to null between loops.

I reviewed almost a dozen SO posts and am somewhat confident using `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` would resolve this. That is where my understanding ends and I am unsuccessful thus far.

Here is the relevant code:

```
SET DATE=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
SET HH=%time:~0,2%
SET MN=%time:~3,2%
SET TSTAMP=Time Run is %HH%%MN%
SET DATETIME=%DATE% at %HH%%MN%
SET LOGFILE="\\nt980a3\CreditFileImagesTransmission\LogFiles\%DATETIME%-File Move Log.txt"

SET MailDst=
SET MailSrc=
SET MailSrcName=Center to LDSD File Mover
SET OKMailSub=A Branch Has Sent You Some Files

ECHO %DATETIME% > %LOGFILE%
ECHO. >> %LOGFILE%

FOR /F "tokens=1" %%A IN (%~dp0SourceServers.txt) DO CALL :ServerMove %%A

:cleanuplogs
PUSHD "\\nt980a3\CreditFileImagesTransmission\LogFiles" &&(
FORFILES /S /M *.txt /D -45 /C "CMD /C DEL /Q @path"
) & POPD

:mailtest
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (%LOGFILE%) DO CALL :searchlog "%%A"

:searchlog
ECHO %1 | find "\\nt">NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO successmail
GOTO exit

:successmail
IF EXIST %temp%\to.txt DEL %temp%\to.txt
FOR %%a IN (%MailDst%) DO ECHO %%a>>%temp%\to.txt
"%~dp0sendmail.exe" /TO=%temp%\to.txt /FROM=%MailSrcName% ^<%MailSrc%^> /REF=%OKMailSub% /MESSAGE=%LOGFILE% /HOST=

:exit
EXIT

:ServerMove
DIR /S /B \\%1\CreditFileImagesTransmission\*.* >> %LOGFILE%
XCOPY /E /C /I /Y "\\%1\CreditFileImagesTransmission\*.*" "\\nt980a3\CreditFileImagesTransmission\%DATE%\%HH%%MN%\"
FOR /D %%P IN ("\\%1\CreditFileImagesTransmission\*.*") DO RMDIR "%%P" /Q /S
DEL /Q /S "\\%1\CreditFileImagesTransmission\*.*"
```

I tried changing `:mailtest` to use `%%B` in both instances but that also fails. Placing `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and its counterpart `ENDLOCAL` before one or the other loop and changing the `%%A` to `!A!` does not work either.

Would someone kindly point out the error in my ways and offer suggestions or resources that will help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%1` is the first parameter provided to the procedure - either from the command-line (in the main procedure) or the parameter following the procedure name in `call :procedurename parameter1`.

In your case, `%1` to `:servermove` is an entry from `SourceServers.txt` and `%1` to `:searchlog` is each line from `%LOGFILE%`.

Since you've censored your batch, what you've posted makes little sense. For instance, the `:searchlogs` routine will take the first line from `%LOGFILE%` and go to `successmail` or `cleanlogs` depending on whether that first line contains the target string `\\nt`. What it does from there, we can't tell.

We're faced with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - trying to fix a solution, not a problem.

---

First problem: Don't use `date` as a user-variable. It's a "magic variable" which contains the date **but** it's overridden by a specific `set` statement.

Having run `:servermove` for each entry in `SourceServers.txt`, you are 
- accumulating a directory list from `\CreditFileImagesTransmission\*.*` on that server.
- copying those files to server `nt980a3` with a date/timestamp **but not including the source-servername** so any duplicate name anywhere will overwrite an earlier version. I suggest you include `%1` into your destination-name.
- deleting subdirectories
- deleting files.

I'd suggest you simply remove the directory `\\%1\CreditFileImagesTransmission\`, then re-create it.

I'd also suggest that you add an extra line

```
goto :eof
```

after the `del /q /s...` line. This will cause execution to be transferred to the end-of-file (the colon in `:eof` is required) and may seem superfluous, but it ensures that the routine has a defined endpoint - if you add a further routine, there is no way the `:servermove` routine will continue into your new code.

After each server has been processed, you proceed to the `:cleanuplogs` routine, which I presume deletes logs older than 45 days.

Your next statement is a real problem. What it will do is grab the very first line of the logfile (which contains `"%DATE% at %HH%%MN%"` with the date resolved as you've set at the start and it then processes this line in `:searchlog`; there is no `\\nt` in this line, so `errorlevel` is set to 1, and the batch proceeds to `:EXIT` (not a good label in my view, since it's a keyword); executes an `exit`and should terminate the batch.

This appears not to be what it is actually doing, and I'm at a loss to explain why.

I'd suggest changing

```
:mailtest
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (%LOGFILE%) DO CALL :searchlog "%%A"

:searchlog
ECHO %1 | find "\\nt">NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO successmail
GOTO exit
```

to

```
:mailtest
find "\\nt" %LOGFILE%>NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO successmail
:failmail
echo "\\nt" was found in the log
pause
GOTO exit
```

but I can't test that...

Comment: I'm sorry; I didn't intend to censor relevant information. It just didn't seem as important. I've updated it to include the full text of the file. Looking at it again, my best guess is the first `FOR`loop is setting %1 to the last server name in the text list (nt-whtever) and the second loop is picking up the same %1 which will always be `>nul`

Comment: I used the `GOTO :EOF` suggestion from both @foxidrive and yourself and changed the code for the `:mailtest` portion to your suggested variation. This has worked beautifully. Now that I better understand the use of `goto :eof`, and a new way to search text, I can use this in other projects. Immensely helpful and great new knowledge - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
:mailtest
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (%LOGFILE%) DO CALL :searchlog "%%A"
```

You are missing a `GOTO :EOF` or similar goto here because it will drop through to the routine below once the above is finished.

```
:searchlog
ECHO %1 | find "\\nt">NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO successmail
GOTO exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can not carry the %1 of first for loop to others. Try to transfer that to another variable like below.

```
:ServerMove

set servername=%1

DIR /S /B \\%servername%\CreditFileImagesTransmission\*.* >> %LOGFILE%
XCOPY /E /C /I /Y "\\%servername%\CreditFileImagesTransmission\*.*"     "\\nt980a3\CreditFileImagesTransmission\%DATE%\%HH%%MN%\"
FOR /D %%P IN ("\\%servername%\CreditFileImagesTransmission\*.*") DO RMDIR "%%P" /Q /S
DEL /Q /S "\\%servername%\CreditFileImagesTransmission\*.*"
```

Cheers, G